# Проверить все ли символы в строке являются заглавными

Tags: python

Учусь немного программированию на сайте: checkio.org. Пошли задания связанные  с текстом, символами.

---

**Задание:**
Проверить все ли символы в строке являются заглавными. Если строка пустая или в ней нет букв - функция должна вернуть **True**.

**Входные данные:** Строка
**Выходные данные:** Логический тип
**Условия:** a-z, A-Z, 1-9 и пробелы

Вот заготовленный код:

```
def is_all_upper(text: str) -> bool:
    # your code here
    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(is_all_upper('ALL UPPER'))

    # These "asserts" are used for self-checking and not for an auto-testing
    assert is_all_upper('ALL UPPER') == True
    assert is_all_upper('all lower') == False
    assert is_all_upper('mixed UPPER and lower') == False
    assert is_all_upper('') == True
    assert is_all_upper('     ') == True
    assert is_all_upper('444') == True
    assert is_all_upper('55 55 5') == True
    print("Coding complete? Click 'Check' to earn cool rewards!")
```

Вот моя версия кода:

```
def is_all_upper(text: str) -> bool:
    if (any(x.isupper() or x.islower() or x.isdigit() or x.isspace() for x in text)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

В данном случае проскакивает только первый тест **`ALL UPPER`**, дальше **`all lower`** не идёт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вообще-то достаточно такого. Проходит все проверки. %)

```
def is_all_upper(text: str) -> bool:
    return text == text.upper()
```

Comment: эх, опередили меня  на  53 секунды

Comment: @ZaArs Я бы даже удалил свой ответ в пользу вашего, но тут нужна в качестве ответа именно функция, которую можно подставить в код из вопроса и проверить `assert`-ы, а не просто результат куда-то присвоить )

Answer (score 2):

Можно не городить многоуровневое or прикручивать ненужные генераторы списков (Списковые включения) и тд...

```py
def is_all_upper(text: str) -> bool:
    if text.upper() == text:
        return True
    elif len(text) == 0:
        return True
    return False
```

Так будет и читать и понимать легче.

Comment: У вас лишние не нужные проверки вообще-то. Хотя это и работает )

Comment: @CrazyElf да видя Ваш вариант ответа понимаю что и правда можно было укоротить код )

Answer (score 2):

```
def is_all_upper(text: str) -> bool:
    return all(map(str.isupper, filter(str.isalpha, text)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Конечно не проходит. Ваша функция вернет `True` если в тексте есть хотя бы одна заглавная буква или хотя бы одна строчная (`islower()`, видимо по ошибке туда попало) или хотя бы один пробел или хотя бы одна цифра. Ее надо просто перевернуть наоборот:

```
def is_all_upper(text: str) -> bool:
    if not (any(x.islower() for x in text)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```